# Simulate second login and query through relations off that

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What ways are there to simulate another login without password (1 user, some playable characters).

It worked when a User created the Team. But it does make more sense that a Character creates/joins a Team. Since a User hasMany Characters, I'm completly screwed. How do I know which of all the Characters creates/joins a Team? It was easy with only 1 User doing this.

Probably missing some general programming skills, but I'm learning!

**Relations**
User hasMany Characters <> Character belongsTo User
Character belongsTo Team <> Team hasMany Characters

**URL**
In team.index I really don't get how to collect all Characters of a Team. The 
url is currently just `/team`. Do I have to use something like `/{character}/{team}`? But I like the simplicity of just `/team`.

**Code**
I came up with variants of the following, but if feels wrong. And is wrong :-D

```
// how would the app know which of the Characters.Team we need. App and me don't know...
$team = auth()->user()->characters()->team()->first();
$characters = \App\Character::where('team_id', $team->id)->get();
```

Clarify this for me, please!

Are the relations wrong?
Is my approach wrong?
Am I missing easy Laravel magic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is probably incorrect, though there is some missing information.

You have stated that a *User* can have many *Characters*, and that a *Team* can have many characters. Can a *Character* be on more than one *Team*?

Since you have ask two questions, I'll answer the first, first.

Since you are asking how to get the Characters of a Team, first consider that you need to know the team before you can look for the characters. So you url might be something like:

```
/team/{team id}/
```

Since you want to specifically know about the characters on the team, and not necessarily about the team itself, you might append the url to ask about those characters.

```
/team/{team id}/characters
```

For the second half of the question, you don't need to know about the user, or their characters. Just come from the same direction in your relation as you did for the url.

```
class Team extends Model {
  public function characters() {
    return $this->hasMany(Character::class);
  }
}
```

In your controller:

```
$team = Team::with(['characters'])->find($teamId);
```